# Should I be wary of ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, best-practices, upsert

I'm new to MySQL, but I have reasonable experience with SQL Server. I know in SQL Server I should be very cautious about using `MERGE` statements because they [can lead to some problems](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/). Are there any special concerns I should have when using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`? Is it considered a best practice in the MySQL community to stick with separate `INSERT/UPDATE` statements like in SQL Server or is it fine to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` broadly for simple upserts?

Comment: Many flavors of `INSERT` 'burn' auto-inc ids when the insert is not performed;  IIRC, IODKU does that when it updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all:

- Yes, it is fine and common practice. For simple upserts, I would say it is best practice.

There are some rather rare cases to worry about and things that may bite you - especially considering that you come from the SQL Server world:

- When you use it against a table with two or more `UNIQUE` constraints. In those cases, you can't easily set to have different behaviours for different constraint violations (while it is possible with the `MERGE` statement).
  An `INSERT` that violates 1 of the 2 unique constraints will go to the `UPDATE` clause. If you want different behaviour depending on which constraint is violated, it will be hard to implement (possibly with some complex `CASE` expressions but may not be feasible in all scenarios).
- A big difference with SQL Server (and all other major SQL implementations) is that `UNIQUE` constraints are checked **after every row `INSERT` or `UPDATE`** and not as the SQL standard says at the end of statement (and don't even think about deferred constraint checks).

  The problem with that is for an `INSERT ... SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...;` statement, the order of how rows are processed matters. If the SELECT creates 2 rows to be inserted that conflict on a UNIQUE constraint, the first one to be processed will be inserted and the second will fall to the `UPDATE` clause (and the order of processing will of course depend on the execution plan). This means non-deterministic result on the state of the table after the statement.
  So one has to be really careful when writing such statements (and any `UPDATE` statement really).
- Related to the previous point, `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statements are marked unsafe for statement based replication, so if you use them you are restricted to row or mixed based replication.